# Inner element should break its floats to float itself

Tags: css, css-float

I have several `div` Elements below each other in my HTML document:

```
#quote
#keyword_tree
#sticky_keywords
#stats
```

I have all of the `float: left` currently, and it works on a big screen. Within `#sticky_keywords`, there are also floated elements which correctly break if the page is very small. The problem is that they are only broken into several lines if the wrapper (`#sticky_keywords`) is already on a line of its own.

How could I get it to break so that it fits next to `#keyword_tree` without specifying static widths?

### big screen

[big http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/m48.png](http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/m48.png)

### small screen

[small screen http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/m49.png](http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/m49.png).

Comment: give `#sticky_keywords` static width, then `#sticky_keywords` will break next to keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this, it works pretty good:

```
#keyword_tree {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#sticky_keywords {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 240px;
}
```

So the keyword tree is fixed (it's a compromise) but the other can use all the space there is.

It works in Firefox, IE9 and Opera:

http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/Auswahl_001_.png

But not so very well in Chromium and Chrome and Rekonq:

http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/17/Auswahl_002.png

I am not sure how it comes up with the extra `margin-right`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a `max-width` for the `#sticky_keywords` so that it always fits next to `#keyword_tree`?

Comment: If I do this, it will not work on screens which are big enough. I'd like to use the whole width.

Comment: BTW, I don't think your other blocks (`Quick Add`,`Statistics`) will float well if your `Sticky Keywords` breaks on small screen.

Comment: it's fixed width or liquid? i think you need specify the width of elements also